# Setting current location for job matching without showing in public profile

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs, profile-page

I really don't like showing my current location publicly.
On the other hand, if I want job matching, I need to fill out the current location info in the *Developer Story* tab, but once I fill it in, it will be synced to profile and shown publicly.

I don't mind employers seeing my information, but I would like to keep a certain amount of privacy to other users/public.

How to avoid this sync?

Comment: Why do you think you need to fill in that field to match jobs?

Comment: @MartijnPieters It will say `your job matching is on hold`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your publicly visible "Location" field is **not** required for job searches, and you can pick in any random location you like in the field, or just leave it blank.

Note that there are two 'location' fields in a user profile:

- "Location", public information, set in the [edit profile section](https://stackoverflow.com/users/edit/current).
- "Where you live", in your Developer Story. You control who can see your Developer Story.

It is the second field that is used in job searches, not the first, as indicated by the (i) information icon next to the "Always include your location" checkbox in your [job search preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/users/jobsearch/current):

> [image: "Where you'd like to work" preferences, showing tooltip on the "Always include your current location" checkbox option. The tooltip reads: "This is the location found in your Developer Story"]

The two fields *can* be synchronized, but that's not a requirement. When you go to the Developer Story "Where you live" field and click to edit it, blue "synchronize with your profile" checkbox becomes available:

> [image]

Make sure that that is *not* set. Then fill in anything you like in your publicly visible *Location* field.